# How to (properly) Create Jobs On Demand

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

## What I would like to do

I would like to create a Kubernetes workflow where **users could POST jobs whenever they wanted**, and they might do it at any time, not necessarily scheduling anything (`CronJobs`), or specifying parallelism or completion requirements, i.e., users could create Jobs on demand.

## How I would do it right now

The way I'm thinking about accomplishing this is by simply applying the `Jobs` to the Kubernetes cluster (I also have to make sure the job doesn't have the same name of a current one because otherwise Kubernetes will think it's a mistake and won't create another one). However, this feels improper because the `Jobs` will be kind of scattered on the cluster and I would lose control over them (though Kubernetes would supposedly automatically manage them optimally).

## Is there a better, proper a way?

I imagine a more proper way of configuring all this is to **create some sort of `Deployment` and `Service` on top of the `Jobs`**, but is that an existing feature on Kubernetes? Huge companies probably have had this problem in the past so I wonder: **what are the best practices for this Kubernetes Jobs On Demand use case?**

Comment: What sort of "control" do you want to have over them? You can control who has permission to create and edit `Jobs` with RBAC. You can control resource usage with `ResourceQuota` and `LimitRange`.

Comment: But `ResourceQuota` and `LimitRange` refer to parallel or sequential `Job` creation, don't they? Can you use them to manage scattered or randomly created `Job`s on the clusters? You could use them to restrict new `Job`s upon creation, but I don't think you can do that for managing them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer but you might be interested in this project: https://github.com/ivoscc/kubernetes-task-runner.

It provides an API to launch one-time tasks as Jobs on a Kubernetes cluster, handles input/output files via GCS and periodically cleans up finished Jobs.